# Parsing XML in PHP with special chars in XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm having trouble parsing the XML below to get the output that I want.  I'm getting the XML below from Commission Junction and don't have control over the output.

```
<cj-api>
   <advertisers total-matched="609" records-returned="10" page-number="1">
      <advertiser>
         <advertiser-id>2283</advertiser-id>
         <account-status>Active</account-status>
         <seven-day-epc>0.00</seven-day-epc>
         <three-month-epc>1.11</three-month-epc>
         <language>en</language>
         <advertiser-name>
            Name here
         </advertiser-name>
         <program-url>http://website.com/</program-url>
         <relationship-status>joined</relationship-status>
         <mobile-tracking-certified>false</mobile-tracking-certified>
         <network-rank>1</network-rank>
         <primary-category>
            <parent>Financial Services</parent>
            <child>Loans</child>
         </primary-category>
         <performance-incentives>false</performance-incentives>
         <actions>
            <action>
               <name>Sale</name>
               <type>sale</type>
               <id>120</id>
               <commission>
                  <default type="item-level">USD 15.00</default>
               </commission>
            </action>
         </actions>
         <link-types>
            <link-type>Text Link</link-type>
            <link-type>Banner</link-type>
            <link-type>Content Link</link-type>
         </link-types>
      </advertiser>
   </advertisers>
</cj-api>
```

I'm using cURL to send the request, and receive the response.  When I print the response I get the XML above, and it all looks good, but when I try to parse the information per below, I get "0" when I would expect to see "2283"

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
print $xml->{"cj-api"}->advertisers->advertiser->advertiser-id;
```

Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

To make me extra happy, if someone could show me how to parse each element to its own variable, I would be extra greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
<?php

$xml_string = <<<XML
<cj-api>
   <advertisers total-matched="609" records-returned="10" page-number="1">
      <advertiser>
         <advertiser-id>2283</advertiser-id>
         <account-status>Active</account-status>
         <seven-day-epc>0.00</seven-day-epc>
         <three-month-epc>1.11</three-month-epc>
         <language>en</language>
         <advertiser-name>
            Name here
         </advertiser-name>
         <program-url>http://website.com/</program-url>
         <relationship-status>joined</relationship-status>
         <mobile-tracking-certified>false</mobile-tracking-certified>
         <network-rank>1</network-rank>
         <primary-category>
            <parent>Financial Services</parent>
            <child>Loans</child>
         </primary-category>
         <performance-incentives>false</performance-incentives>
         <actions>
            <action>
               <name>Sale</name>
               <type>sale</type>
               <id>120</id>
               <commission>
                  <default type="item-level">USD 15.00</default>
               </commission>
            </action>
         </actions>
         <link-types>
            <link-type>Text Link</link-type>
            <link-type>Banner</link-type>
            <link-type>Content Link</link-type>
         </link-types>
      </advertiser>
      <advertiser>
         <advertiser-id>2284</advertiser-id>
         <account-status>Not Active</account-status>
         <seven-day-epc>0.00</seven-day-epc>
         <three-month-epc>1.11</three-month-epc>
         <language>en</language>
         <advertiser-name>
            Name here
         </advertiser-name>
         <program-url>http://website.com/</program-url>
         <relationship-status>joined</relationship-status>
         <mobile-tracking-certified>false</mobile-tracking-certified>
         <network-rank>1</network-rank>
         <primary-category>
            <parent>Financial Services</parent>
            <child>Loans</child>
         </primary-category>
         <performance-incentives>false</performance-incentives>
         <actions>
            <action>
               <name>Sale</name>
               <type>sale</type>
               <id>120</id>
               <commission>
                  <default type="item-level">USD 15.00</default>
               </commission>
            </action>
         </actions>
         <link-types>
            <link-type>Text Link</link-type>
            <link-type>Banner</link-type>
            <link-type>Content Link</link-type>
         </link-types>
      </advertiser>
   </advertisers>
</cj-api>
XML;

$parse = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach($parse->advertisers->advertiser as $advertiser){
    $id = (string) $advertiser->{"advertiser-id"};
    var_dump($id);
}
?>
```

Comment: Excellent.  To get the other elements out, would I just add them into the foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to get the content of all nodes that don't have children. Those that have will need another `foreach` inside the current one. For example, if you want to get the `<link-types>`, you'll have to do `$links = array(); foreach($advertiser->{"link-types"}->children() as $link){ $links[] = (string) $link; }`. By the way, it would be a lot easier if you could use `JSON` instead of `XML`. If you have the choice, go with JSON.

Comment: Yeah, JSON used to be an option when they allowed SOAP.  When they switched to REST, they nixed the JSON too.

Comment: In that case you'll have to `foreach` all of the elements and `foreach` their children as well. You can also try using `xpath`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("id is %s", $xml->{"advertisers"}->advertiser->{"advertiser-id"});
```